# what is the best way for doing same sql query in every html pages

Tags: python, django, query-optimization

I have 10 html pages and 10 function in views.py file. I have same query in every function (and same results). So what is the best optimization way not to do same sql query in every pages?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear whether you mean you don't want to hit the database multiple times, or you don't want to write out the actual code multiple times (which is a major part of being "pythonic").

If it's the latter, then look into [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/). These are very powerful tools that allow you to write far less boiler plate code and make your app far more maintainable. For example you could write one base class that contains the query, and all the other views could inherit from this base class and add their own template/whatever it is that you're changing from view to view.

If it's the former, and you're worried about database hits then I'd question A) Is the query really that expensive that it needs to be optimised? and B) If it is that expensive, are you sure there's a very good reason that you need to repeat it in 10 different views?

If the answer is yes to both of those then you'll want to look into caching using something like [memcached](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#memcached) and django's caching framework.

In future please include more information in your question. Examples of your views/explanations of WHY you need to do what you're trying to do can not only help people answer your question, but also point you in the direction of a better solution to your problem.

Comment: I take into consideration "dont repeat yourself". I am talking about my profile part. I want profile information to exist in every pages. forexample twitter. Your following, tweets, followed vs exist in every html pages. (sory my bad english) So both of them is important for me I guess.

Comment: The short answer here is "Don't optimize prematurely". Pulling profile information from your database is such a small transaction that you're going to see almost no difference between caching and non caching. Even for more expensive queries, memcached would be more than enough to handle it.